# How to Disable Page Piling on Mobile?

Tags: javascript, pagepiling.js

I am using this page piling script on my website and I want to disable this page piling on mobile so how can o do this please suggest me

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js

Answer (score 0):

Check the `window.innerWidth` and if it less than a specified pixel width don't apply the page piling.

Usage from the docs [here](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js#initialization)

html

```
<div id="pagepiling">
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pagepiling').pagepiling();
});
```

With your modification.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if (window.innerWidth > 320) {
       $('#pagepiling').pagepiling();
   } else {
     // do something else or do nothing
   }
});
```